# How does the Rifleman daily mission work?

Tags: war-clicks

In the [War Clicks](https://warclicks.com/) game, there is a daily mission called Rifleman, which has the following text:

> Fight your enemies and do at least 2500 clicks to complete today's mission.

How does this work?

More specifically:

- Which enemies count?  Regular battles?  Boss battles?  Invasion?
- Do autoclicks count?  Support clicks?  Or just manual clicks?

This matters because in War Clicks you get to choose from two daily missions to attempt.  So it's important to know how difficult each daily mission is to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that regular battles and the autoclicker count.  I have established that by the simple method of starting the autoclicker multiple times without engaging in any other battles in between.  The progress tracker is moving.

I have not attempted a boss battle nor used the support power clicker.  When I do, I'm not sure that I'll be able to tell if the progress tracker moves, as it moves so little most of the time.  Perhaps if someone had the game set up so that the next click was a boss battle at the beginning of the mission.  A similar check might work for the support power clicker, although it would essentially waste the support power attacks for the day.

I didn't see movement of the tracker with Invasion.  However, it is possible that the movement was too small for me to detect.

In summary, it looks like the primary way to get the clicks is the autoclicker in regular battles.